# spacy can't find GPU when training model

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to train a basic NER model on a Paperspace P4000 server, Spacy 3.4.1 and python 3.9.16. I used the Quickstart template to created a base_config.cfg etc. Everything seems to be formatted correctly because it works fine when I set the config to use the CPU.

When I set it to use the GPU, it uses the CPU regardless.

`python -m spacy init fill-config ./spacy_model_gpu/base_config_gpu.cfg ./spacy_model_gpu/config.cfg`

`python -m spacy train ./spacy_model_gpu/config.cfg --output ./output --paths.train ./spacy_model_gpu/train.spacy --paths.dev ./spacy_model_cpu/train.spacy`

If I add `--gpu-id 0` to the spacy train command as suggested [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7121), it throws this error:

```
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 74, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/typer/main.py", line 532, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 45, in train_cli
    train(config_path, output_path, use_gpu=use_gpu, overrides=overrides)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 67, in train
    setup_gpu(use_gpu)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 581, in setup_gpu
    require_gpu(use_gpu)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/thinc/util.py", line 195, in require_gpu
    raise ValueError("No GPU devices detected")
ValueError: No GPU devices detected
```

`nvidia-smi` gives me this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.73.05    Driver Version: 510.73.05    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P4000        Off  | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 46%   37C    P8     6W / 105W |      2MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and here's some further due diligence for GPU existence:

```
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>> torch.cuda.device(0)
<torch.cuda.device object at 0x7f4a4d97a880>
>>> torch.cuda.current_device()
0
>>> torch.cuda.device_count()
1
>>> torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
'Quadro P4000'
```

Comment: Do you have CuPy installed?

Comment: it turns out I do not, nor did I have CUDA toolkit installed ... but when I tried to install it I got a "W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times" error

Comment: there's a little more detail on my issue here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/12410

Answer (score 0):

turns out I didnt have `cupy` installed, and I was trying to install the wrong version.

this is working now!